# TD class is not changing not taking effect

Tags: html, css, radio-button

So I have a td with a radio button. I have the following markup:

```css
.create-agreement-radio {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.create-agreement-radio td {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

table .create-agreement-radio {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<td class="text-center create-agreement-radio">
  <span class="radio-custom radio-primary" data-lastselected="0" data-bind="event: { click: function(data, event) { $root.contractRadioClick(data, event, this) } }">
<input type="radio" name="contractSelectRadio" data-bind=" attr: { id: 'contractSelected' + $index() }">
<label data-bind="attr: { 'for': 'contractSelected' + $index() }"></label>
</span>
</td>
```

I am unsure why my CSS changes are not taking effect on the radio button, but if I add styling to the element it works fine, just not when I apply a class to the td.

Comment: Are those asteriks meant to bold `**create-agreement-radio**`? The bolding syntax doesn't work when wrapped in backticks :` or <code>; blocks

Comment: Did you check the `box-model`/`computed styles` in the developer tools if the styles are being applied/overridden ??

Comment: @zer00ne, no thats not in my syntax its to illustrate the class in the markup.

Comment: @Rob markup as in HTML? That's markdown which is more presentation than anything else HTML is structure layout and wrapping a className in double asterisks isn't HTML AFAIK

Comment: @zer00ne thats markdown you're correct.

Comment: changing `**create-agreement-radio**` to `create-agreement-radio` seems to have effect

Comment: If I correct your error (i.e. the fact that the td is not in a table) it works as expected. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvqLpG

Comment: @MrLister Okay but Its in a table etc on my page, which css class did it seem to work for?

Comment: The td is the only element that has the class. Can you create a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the issue? Otherwise your question will be closed as caused by a simple typographical error.

Comment: @MrLister as in `.create-agreement-radio td {
  padding-top: 20px;
}`

Comment: @Rob No, that selector does not do anything in your snippet. In [my codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvqLpG) I only needed the first selector. Again, can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: So it turns out the theme I am using is overriding the class in my custom stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to over-ride the theme.css, I had to add an `ID` to my class so it now looks like: `<td class="text-center" id="create-agreement-radio">`

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this, I surrounded you `td` with a `table` tag and then removed the arteris `*` from `create-agreement-radio`. Everything works fine.

```css
.create-agreement-radio {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.create-agreement-radio td {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

table .create-agreement-radio {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<td class="text-center create-agreement-radio">
  <span class="radio-custom radio-primary" data-lastselected="0" data-bind="event: { click: function(data, event) { $root.contractRadioClick(data, event, this) } }">
<input type="radio" name="contractSelectRadio" data-bind=" attr: { id: 'contractSelected' + $index() }">
<label data-bind="attr: { 'for': 'contractSelected' + $index() }"></label>
</span>
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Sure, but the OP remarked off-handedly that their original code does have the table and that there were no asterisks in their syntax.